# Chrome Android redirects to web.bwanet.ca

Tags: chrome-for-android, malware, url

Downloaded Sophos Intercept X today cause my Chrome browser kept opening to `https://web.bwanet.ca` all of a sudden + all my open tabs were gone.

Is it due to Sophos? If so, is there a specific feature in the Sophos app that can stop future hijacks?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Sophos download, but as far as `bwanet` is concerned, on several online forums (see below) people mention that if your phone is from Bell/Virgin, then that is who is "hijacking" your home page to `bwanet`.

The solution is to go into your browser settings and change the home page Bell/Virgin sets upon every browser install.

I gathered this from the following pages:

- [r/virginmobile on Reddit (2021-01-20)](https://www.reddit.com/r/virginmobile/comments/l8pc82/virgin_canada_bwanetca/)
- [Google Chrome Help (2019-09-02)](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/13436358/my-chrome-browser-is-default-opening-in-web-bwanet-ca-seems-an-virus-of-broswer-hijack)
- [Samsung Community (2021-12-21)](https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/others/web-bwanet-ca/td-p/14469716)

Answer (score 0):

First it is totally unclear why the tabs are gone. Can be anything between a simple bug in the web browser or a sophisticated attack.

And second nobody knows what bugs and vulnerabilities are hidden in the browsers you mentioned and additionally what bugs and vulnerabilities are introduced in the next version.

Hence from my perspective the only answer you can get is `NO`. Nothing can prevent or stop unknown problems in a constantly updated software browsing constantly changing web sites.

You can always protect yourself only against known problems. This also applies to  software like Sophos Intercept X.

Comment: well on windows desktop years ago i remember lots of software that worked well to stop browser hijacker malware, but on android i'm unfamiliar with which part of the anti-virus/malware apps work to protect browsers.